# Grouping a class using stream java 8 or in SQL whichever is best

Tags: java, sql, java-stream

The data is something like this

```
    head child assigned total
[   Mas   Mas1     2    5
,   Mas   Mas2     0    5
,   Usr   usr1     4    4
,   Usr   usr2     1    3
,   Inv   Inv1     3    5
,   Inv   Inv2     2    3
,   Inv   Inv3     2    3
,   Inv   Inv4     1    3
]
```

I want sum of their child for a particular header.

I am using partition in sql

```
select head,
SUM(childAssigned) over (partition by am.acl_group) as assignedHead,
sum(childTotal) over (partition by am.acl_group) as totalHead,
child,
childAssigned,
childTotal
```

Since, "partition by" is not supported by HQL astquerytranslatorfactory, I am using this as a native query

I have a class which is holding SQL Response

```
class AclList{
    String head;
    Integer assignedHead;
    Integer totalHead;
    String child;
    Integer assignedChild;
    Integer totalChild;
}
```

The data is something like this

```
[   Mas 2   10  Mas1    2   5
,   Mas 2   10  Mas2    0   5
,   Usr 5   7   usr1    4   4
,   Usr 5   7   usr2    1   3
,   Inv 8   14  Inv1    3   5
,   Inv 8   14  Inv2    2   3
,   Inv 8   14  Inv3    2   3
,   Inv 8   14  Inv4    1   3
]
```

I want a response which will groupify child of same header.

Response should be like ResponseClass(type, assigned, total, List)

```
[ 
  { 
    "type":"MAS",
    "assigned":"2",
    "total":"10",
    "subType":[ 
      { 
        "type":"MAS1",
        "assigned":"2",
        "total":"5"
      },
      { 
        "type":"MAS2",
        "assigned":"0",
        "total":"5"
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "type":"USR",
    "assigned":"5",
    "total":"7",
    "subType":[ 
      { 
        "type":"USR1",
        "assigned":"4",
        "total":"4"
      },
      { 
        "type":"USR2",
        "assigned":"1",
        "total":"3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

class Details(type, assigned, total)
My approach is keeping header in hashmap's key, child in hashmap's value
Since all 3 columns of a head are same, So, equals, hashcode take care.

class ChildDetails(List)
HashMap

```
Iterate sql response
if hashmap.contains(head) //exist
    fetch value, add new one in list
    hashmap.put(head, updated)
else
    create header,
    create child, add it to a blank list
    hashmap.put(head, new list)
```

Again iterate hashmap, arrange it in new json response

But, this is a cumbersome proces & inefficient.

Is there anyway it can be done with JAVA  stream() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it can be done with JAVA stream()**

```
package com.bbc.enums;

import lombok.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<AclList> aclLists = Arrays.asList(
                new AclList("Mas", 2, 10, "Mas1", 2, 5),
                new AclList("Mas", 2, 10, "Mas2", 0, 5),
                new AclList("USR", 5, 7, "USR1", 4, 4),
                new AclList("USR", 5, 7, "USR2", 1, 3),
                new AclList("Inv", 8, 14, "Inv1", 3, 5),
                new AclList("Inv", 8, 14, "Inv2", 2, 3),
                new AclList("Inv", 8, 14, "Inv3", 2, 3),
                new AclList("Inv", 8, 14, "Inv4", 1, 3)

        );

        Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<AclList>>>> collect = aclLists.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AclList::getHead, Collectors.groupingBy(AclList::getAssignedHead,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(AclList::getTotalHead))));

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> resList = new ArrayList<>();
        collect.forEach((k1, v1) -> {
            HashMap<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
            res.put("type", k1);
            v1.forEach((k2, v2) -> {
                res.put("assigned", k2);
                v2.forEach((k3, v3) -> {
                    res.put("total", k3);
                    List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    v3.forEach(aclList -> {
                        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                        map1.put("type", aclList.getChild());
                        map1.put("assigned", aclList.getAssignedChild());
                        map1.put("total", aclList.getTotalChild());
                        list.add(map1);
                    });
                    res.put("subType", list);
                });
            });
            resList.add(res);
        });
        System.out.println(resList);
        // if you want json response then
        System.out.println(listmap_to_json_string(resList));
    }


    public static String listmap_to_json_string(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        JSONArray json_arr = new JSONArray();
        for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
            JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                try {
                    json_obj.put(key, value);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            json_arr.put(json_obj);
        }
        return json_arr.toString();
    }
}


@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
class AclList {
    String head;
    Integer assignedHead;
    Integer totalHead;
    String child;
    Integer assignedChild;
    Integer totalChild;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) stream `Collector` can help you here.

**Setup:**

```java
// original data AclList
class AclList {

  String head;
  Integer assignedHead;
  Integer totalHead;
  String child;
  Integer assignedChild;
  Integer totalChild;
}

// Subtype in the response object based on Json
class SubType {

  String type;
  Integer assigned;
  Integer total;

  public SubType(String type, Integer assigned, Integer total) {
    this.type = type;
    this.assigned = assigned;
    this.total = total;
  }
}

// Response object based on Json
class Response {

  String type;
  Integer assigned;
  Integer total;
  List<SubType> subType;

  public Response(String type, Integer assigned, Integer total, List<SubType> subType) {
    this.type = type;
    this.assigned = assigned;
    this.total = total;
    this.subType = subType;
  }
}
```

**Step 1:** Group the data by the `head` field in the class `AclList`. This step returns a `Map` of the distinct `head` values as the key, and a list of `AclList` objects as the value, grouped by the key.

```java
Map<String, List<AclList>> groupedByHead = data
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(acl -> acl.head));
```

**Step 2:** Just manipulate the `Map` to create the required response structure.

```java
List<Response> response = groupedByHead.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 0)
    .map(e -> {
          List<AclList> acls = e.getValue();
          AclList first = acls.get(0);
          List<SubType> children = acls
              .stream()
              .map(acl -> new SubType(acl.child, acl.assignedChild, acl.totalChild))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

          return new Response(first.head, first.assignedHead, first.totalHead, children);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I'm not sure about your constraints, but it would be better do just do the grouping operations in your database queries instead of doing it in code.

Comment: I am doing JOIN, count(), sum(),  over partition by to get the final response I posted.

Comment: [   Mas Mas1    2   5
,   Mas Mas2    0   5
,   Usr   usr1    4   4
,   Usr   usr2    1   3,
I need to list header total from child total's sum, header assigned from child assigned's sum

Comment: head, child, assignedChild, totalChild without assignedHead, totalHead, which I am deriving from SQL

Comment: The input you've shared is not what you've mentioned in your comments here. I have written a solution assuming that the data you've shared is the input. Please share the actual raw data (and the class structure) that you have as the input and the expected JSON response that you need.