# How can i convert a plain JSON object to nested JSON Object

Tags: json, java-8

I have 14 plain json objects and want to form a one nested json output

Input:

```
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Mellisa",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "Rob",
 "Subject": "botany"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Mellisa",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "Rob",
 "Subject": "zoology"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Mellisa",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "kevin",
 "Subject": "botany"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Mellisa",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "kevin",
 "Subject": "botany"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Petter",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "tim",
 "Subject": "botany"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Petter",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "tim",
 "Subject": "zoology"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Petter",
 "grade": "sixth",
 "Student name": "david",
 "Subject": "botany"
}
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Petter",
  "grade": "sixth",
  "Student name": "david",
  "Subject": "zoology"
}
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Mellisa",
  "grade": "seventh",
  "Student name": "jane",
  "Subject": "math"
 }
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Mellisa",
  "grade": "seventh",
  "Student name": "Lin",
  "Subject": "physics"
}
{
 "School": "Happy",
 "Teacher": "Mellisa",
 "grade": "seventh",
 "Student name": "jane",
 "Subject": "math"
}
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Mellisa",
  "grade": "seventh",
  "Student name": "Lin",
  "Subject": "physics"
 }
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Petter",
  "grade": "seventh",
  "Student name": "jane",
  "Subject": "math"
 }
{
  "School": "Happy",
  "Teacher": "Petter",
  "grade": "seventh",
  "Student name": "Lin",
  "Subject": "physics"
 }
```

Output:

```
{
"School": "Happy",
"Teacher": [
    {
        "name": "petter",
        "Student": [
            {
                "name": "Lin",
                "grade":"seventh",
                "Subject": [
                    {
                        "name": "physics"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "math"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Jane",
                "grade":"seventh",
                "Subject": [
                    {
                        "name": "physics"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "math"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: I am trying but i am not able to figure out the logic

Comment: share your logic please!

Comment: what I am trying to achieve here is I want to put it in nested structure if the key are same and value are different. And this hierarchy is nested to 7 levels. I dont get any solution for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674170/grouping-a-class-using-stream-java-8-or-in-sql-whichever-is-best litte insight. check grouping by in java 8 stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question is so verbose! and it requires to know about some josn library.(I used [this library](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/))

first of all you need define a class to map your json data to it. since some json keys started with uppercase and it is unlike of java syntax I used `@JsonProperty` annotation.

```
 class JsonData {
    @JsonProperty("School")
    private String school;
    @JsonProperty("Teacher")
    private String teacher;
    private String grade;
    @JsonProperty("Student name")
    private String studentName;
    @JsonProperty("Subject")
    private String subject;
}
```

To convert json string to object you can use below code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<JsonData> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<JsonData>>() {});
```

after converting json string to object, grouped it into several properties.(school, teacher, student)

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<JsonData>>>> result = list.stream()
         .collect(Collectors
                 .groupingBy(JsonData::getSchool, Collectors
                        .groupingBy(JsonData::getTeacher, Collectors
                            .groupingBy(JsonData::getStudentName, Collectors.toList()))));
```

the output of it is:

> ```
> {Happy=
>    {Mellisa=
>     {Lin=[
>       JsonData{school='Happy', ....},
>       JsonData{school='Happy', ....}],
> ```

in the last step by looping over previous result, final object will create.

```
ResultData resultData = null;
Teacher teacher = null;
Student student;
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<JsonData>>>> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    resultData = new ResultData(entry.getKey());
   for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<JsonData>>> entry1 : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        teacher = new Teacher(entry1.getKey());
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<JsonData>> entry2 : entry1.getValue().entrySet()) {
             student = new Student(entry2.getKey());
             for (JsonData jsonData : entry2.getValue()) {
                    student.setGrade(jsonData.getGrade());
                    student.getSubject().add(new Subject(jsonData.getSubject()));
                }
                teacher.getStudent().add(student);
            }
        }
        resultData.getTeacher().add(teacher);
    }
```

other classes that used in this:

```
class ResultData {
  private String school;
  private List<Teacher> teacher = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Teacher {
  private String name;
  private List<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Student {
  private String name;
  private String grade;
  private List<Subject> subject = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Subject {
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hadi, It worked! One question if I want to set the ids for each class can i do teacher.setId(entry2.gettValue().get(0).getTeacherId()); or for School resultData.setId(entry1.getValue().get(0).get(0).getSchoolId). is this right way of doing it?

Comment: @Vivek, yes you can. just check its nullity.